# How to create formulas to compute new variables in R considering names in a data frame and their column value

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem in R to compute new variables in R. The dput version of my data frame is:

```
structure(list(sexo = c(-22.84754, -30.95001, -37.36658, -45.64382, 
-54.9466, -0.1732915), cli_edad = c(5.972972, 11.67697, 16.46362, 
26.57938, 47.19307, 0.1037254), edad2 = c(-0.0637181, -0.1199798, 
-0.1600652, -0.2424397, -0.4273092, -0.001068), veces_mora_ago12 = c(-100.6952, 
-166.6598, -391.6087, -710.2349, -1098.773, -0.3525356), veces_mora_sep12 = c(20.06456, 
162.5816, 388.1126, 738.8196, 1181.483, 0.2907068), veces_mora_oct12 = c(79.44273, 
-15.99917, -13.33856, 9.459844, 103.7592, -0.0863719)), .Names = c("sexo", 
"cli_edad", "edad2", "veces_mora_ago12", "veces_mora_sep12", 
"veces_mora_oct12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

The rows of that data frame are the coefficients of different models. When I load a data frame in R I need to compute a new variable for each model. For example the loaded data frame `DF` will have the same names that `z` but in this case I have to compute 6 additional variables for `DF` this variables are defined for different formulas, for example this considering names of `z` and the first row of `z`:

```
DF$I1=-22.8475400*DF$sexo+5.9729720*DF$cli_edad-0.0637181*DF$edad2-100.6952000*DF$veces_mora_ago12+20.0645600*DF$veces_mora_sep12+79.4427300*DF$veces_mora_oct12
```

Like last formula I have to write 5 additional formulas for the combination between names and second row of `z` until names and sixth row of `z`.

I don't know if it is possible to create in R this formulas and when I load a data frame can apply these to compute the new variables. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The output of I1 you gave is `[1]  17410.94776  19549.83787  47112.85467  88294.47367 144127.32240 39.04883`.  What were you expecting as output?

Comment: Dear @JLLagrange it would be DF$I1 because I wat to apply that formula to a different data frame of `z` that has the same names that `z`

Comment: Can you say again what `z` is, and how it relates to `DF`?  If it is another data frame with the same number of columns as `DF`, you might think of doing this as vector algebra.

Comment: In your case, this would be `DF %*% as.matrix(c(-22.8, 5.97, -0.06, -100.69, 20.1, 79.4))`.  Then you could loop over data frames and multiply by that vector.  But maybe I don't understand what `z` is

Comment: Dear @JLLagrange `z` has in each row the different information of coefficients to compute a new value for a new data frame. In this case `DF` is the new data frame. The object is to get in a new column the sum product of each row of `z` with each row of a new data frame.

Comment: It sounds like you do want matrix multiplication -- is `as.matrix(DF) %*% t(as.matrix(z))` not what you're looking for?  Can you give a sample `z` to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example:

```
> -22.8475400*DF$sexo+5.9729720*DF$cli_edad-0.0637181*DF$edad2-100.6952000*DF$veces_mora_ago12+20.0645600*DF$veces_mora_sep12+79.4427300*DF$veces_mora_oct12
[1]  17410.94776  19549.83787  47112.85467  88294.47367 144127.32240     39.04883
```

As @JJLagrange says I think you want this???

```
DM=as.matrix(DF)
DM%*% t(DM)
             1           2           3            4            5           6
1  17410.94776  19549.8379  47112.8547   88294.4737  144127.3224  39.0488287
2  19549.83787  55558.5082 129927.5614  240057.8018  375800.3450 113.9736682
3  47112.85467 129927.5614 305834.0191  566896.3661  890283.7105 260.2182340
4  88294.47367 240057.8018 566896.3661 1053167.3837 1658033.7139 475.0128054
5 144127.32240 375800.3450 890283.7105 1658033.7139 2619216.6537 736.2772169
6     39.04883    113.9737    260.2182     475.0128     736.2772   0.2570419
```